# Smoothing out transforms

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I am modifying frames of UIImageViews using `CGAffineTransform` methods and then calling setNeedsDisplay on the parent view. This works correctly, only the transforms are very rigid.

How can I smooth out the animations? I have looked into quadratic interpolation but I am not sure what to do with it. As I am scaling these or rotating them and I calculate the next value to set on the UIImageView, but I do not know where to apply interpolation if I do not know the points.

I have a currentRotation value and a currentScale value, and I can get the next ones when they are fed to the method, but am not sure how to progressively animate from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encapsulating that in an `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`? I have something like this in one of my apps, and works smoothly:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     _chevronImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((int)(arc4random() % 100));
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

EDIT: I call this in the `-drawRect:` method.